# Trouble with xpath construction

Tags: xpath, scrapy

Having a hard time with constructing the proper xpath for [this page](http://mymobile.ge/new/v2.php?cat=69).
I'm trying to build the spider (have done before few times, so I know the basics) for parsing the names, urls and prices for products but any xpath I tried in scrapy shell doesn't go past 6th item.

last xpath I tried was `sel.xpath('//table[@width="1000"]')` and yet again, it finished parsing items on *Huawei Ascend G700*

Can anybody tell me what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this xpath:

```
//table[@width='1000']//td/table[@class='probg']
```

to locate all product elements on this page.